# Baby Rudin 1.1, the need of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

The investigation:

[image]

Why is the claim that "*A contains no largest number and B contains no smallest*" tantamount to saying that there's a gap at $ \sqrt{2}$ (in terms of rationals)? Rudin specifically restricts $p^2 < 2 $ and $p^2 > 2$, so how can that be used to justify the fact that there's no rational $p = \sqrt{2}$. I get the first part of the example, and I understand why there's no largest and smallest rational number in those sets, but there would also be no largest or smallest real in analogous real number sets, isn't that true?

Comment: The first part of the discussion (before "We now examine this situation a little more closely.") is a proof of $\sqrt{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$. The second part attempts to intuitively explain the gap at $\sqrt{2}$ by the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not satisfy the axiom of completeness: $A \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ is bounded from above, but it does not have a supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$. Similar for $B$.

Comment: In the first part of this section Rudin proves that equality is not possible. Then he analyses the cases that are left.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q} = \{q \mid q < \sqrt{2}\} \cup \{q \mid q > \sqrt{2}\}$, and that's it. But $\mathbb{R} = \{r \mid r < \sqrt{2}\} \cup \{r \mid r > \sqrt{2}\} \cup \{\sqrt{2}\}$. Or if you write $\mathbb{Q} = \{q \mid q \leq \sqrt{2}\} \cup \{q \mid q \geq \sqrt{2}\}$, these sets have no largest (resp. smallest) members, while the corresponding sets of real numbers $\mathbb{R} = \{r \mid r \leq \sqrt{2}\} \cup \{r \mid r \geq \sqrt{2}\}$ do, namely, $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

There are indeed order-gaps in $\mathbb Q.$ We have $\mathbb Q=\{q\in \mathbb Q:q^2<2\}\cup \{q\in \mathbb Q: q^2>2\}.$

$$ \text {Therefore }\quad \mathbb Q=A\cup B$$ $$\text {where }\quad  A=\{q\in\mathbb Q:q\leq 0\lor (q>0\land q^2<2)\}$$ $$\text {and }\quad B=\{q\in \mathbb Q: 0<q\land q^2>2\}.$$ Every member of $A$ is less than every member of $B$ so every $a\in A$ is a lower bound for $B$ and every $b\in B$ is an upper bound for A.

The point is that, because $A$ has no largest member and $B$ has no least member, therefore no member of $\mathbb Q$ is a $lub$ for $A,$ and no member of $\mathbb Q$ is a $glb$ for $B.$

So a sequence of members of $\mathbb Q,$ that heuristically "should" converge to a number, may fail to converge to a member of $\mathbb Q.$

BTW. Another way to show that $B$ has no $\min$ and that  $A$ has no $\max$ is to use a method written about by Hero (Heron) of Alexandria circa 100 A.D. for finding approximate square roots:

(i). For $y>0$ and $x>0$ with $x^2>y,$ let $x'=\frac {1}{2}(x+\frac {y}{x}).$ Then $0<x'<x$ and $x'^2>y.$ In particular, with $y=2$ and $x\in B$ we have $x>x'\in B.$.

(ii). For $y>0$ and $z>0$ with $z^2<y,$ let $x=\frac {y}{z}$ and let $x'$ be as in (i) above, and let $z^*=\frac {y}{x'}.$ Then $0<z<z^*$ and $(z^*)^2<y.$ In particular with $y=2$ and $0<z\in A$ we have $z<z^*\in A.$

BTW. For $x_1>0$ and $y>0,$ let $x_{n+1}=\frac {1}{2}(x_n+\frac {y}{x_n}).$  The sequence $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges (in $\mathbb R$) rapidly to $\sqrt y\;,$ which is what Heron wrote about.